# Multiple registrations in .net core DI possible implications

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

Will anything bad happen if there are multiple registrations of services in .net core's DI? For example let's say we have the following code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //....
    services.AddHealthChecks();
    //...
}
```

And in another (extension maybe) class we use `services.AddHealthChecks()` again. Will this mess the DI's  container or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You can register a service several times without an exception has thrown. The problem is when you register a service several times with different scope. consider following example:

```cs
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void Print();
}

public class MyInterface : IMyInterface
{
    public void Print()
    {
    }
}
```

And let's register `IMyInterface` with two different scopes:

```cs
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddScoped<IMyInterface, MyInterface>();
        services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface, MyInterface>();

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var scope = provider.CreateScope();
            using (scope)
            {
                var myInterface = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMyInterface>();
                Console.WriteLine(myInterface.GetHashCode());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First, register `IMyInterface` in the following order:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyInterface, MyInterface>();
services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface, MyInterface>();
```

[image]

As you can see we get a singleton instance of `MyInterface` and the hashcode is the same.

Now let's change it to this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface, MyInterface>();
services.AddScoped<IMyInterface, MyInterface>();
```

[image]

Now we get the scoped type of `MyInterface` and the hashcode is different each time. You always get the last registered scope of your type.

Look at [AddHealthChecks](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/HealthChecks/HealthChecks/src/DependencyInjection/HealthCheckServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L26) code:

```cs
public static IHealthChecksBuilder AddHealthChecks(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.TryAddSingleton<HealthCheckService, DefaultHealthCheckService>();
    services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IHostedService, HealthCheckPublisherHostedService>());
    return new HealthChecksBuilder(services);
}
```

By adding `services.AddHealthChecks();` more than one time, you just registering `HealthCheckService` and `IHostedService` as a singleton services and I think it doesn't affect the health check functionality.

With the following extension, you can find duplicate registration:

```cs
public static class ServiceDescription
{
    private static List<IGrouping<Type, ServiceDescriptor>> Descriptors;

    public static IHostBuilder ConfigureServiceDescriptionCheck(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
    {
        hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            Descriptors = services.Where(i => !i.ServiceType.Assembly.FullName.Contains("Microsoft"))
                .GroupBy(p => p.ServiceType)
                .Where(x => x.Count() > 1).ToList();

        });

        return hostBuilder;
    }

    public static IHost UseServiceDescriptionCheck(this IHost host)
    {
        var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

        Descriptors.ForEach(item =>
        {
            var count = item.Count();
            logger.LogWarning("Service of type {Key} has been registered {count} times", item.Key, count);
        });

        return host;
    }
}
```

And use it in this way:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().UseServiceDescriptionCheck().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .ConfigureServiceDescriptionCheck();
}
```

Read [this article](https://anthonygiretti.com/2020/01/20/check-and-log-multiple-registrations-of-a-same-service-in-asp-net-core-3-1/) to get more details.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer @mohsen-esmailpour. What you say is also something I was thinking too when talking about implications. I did some more digging though. I debugged the code in order to see what was in `services` after `services.AddHealthChecks()` and after another call to the same `service.AddHealthChecks()`. The services added the first time was `HealthCheckService` and `IHostedService`. The second time, nothing changed. So, internally there is a mechanism that prevents this, I suppose.

Comment: For example, if I register `IMyInterface` as scoped service more than one time, nothing will happen, only more than registration exists in the service collection. I updated the answer.